# Why do files I have opened remain open unless I Dispose() them?

Tags: c#, file, openfiledialog

In my application, I am using OpenFileDialog and then assign the loaded file to LoadedFile field.
I have found out that if I open 3 files, all remained open (access denied when trying to do anything with them) and I am not sure why?
However when doing this, it works fine:

```
if(LoadedFile!=null)
{
  LoadedFile.Dispose();
  LoadedFile=null;
}

LoadedFile=openFileDialog.GetFile() //pseudo code
```

Is it enough? Why all files remained "open" if I do not do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly close an open file, it remains open and you get the access violation exception.

You should open the file within a `using` statement in order to ensure that it is disposed of correctly (which is what your code does, manually).

```
using(File aFile = File.Open("path to file"))
{
 // use the file
}
```

---

Note:

This has *nothing* to do with memory (which you don't control yourself, as .NET is garbage collected). It is about resource management, in this case open file handles.

Comment: well but what is memory, is it not resource?

Comment: @Miria Memory is a resource; but not all resources are memory. This one is not memory, but (as Oded said) a file handle.

Answer (score 1):

Until you call `Dispose()` (i.e., stating that you don't need it any more), the file will be locked.

Answer (score 0):

You must close a file once you're done with it. `Dispose` does that.